# I want data of 50 random array with 5 column and 10 row, with unique and no duplicate value. Here why duplicate values are showing?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim FillRange As Range, c As Range

Set FillRange = Range("A1:A10")

For x = 0 To 4

Set FillRange = Range("A1:A10").Offset(, x)

For Each c In FillRange

    Do

        c.Value = Int((50 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)

    Loop Until WorksheetFunction.CountIf(FillRange, c.Value) < 2

Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You have duplicates because random numbers aren't unique. They are random. Since you want the numbers from 1 to 50 the numbers aren't random. They are unique. Therefore the location is random. Check each random cell before you write to it. If it isn't empty select another random cell.

Comment: Because it is Random! Imagine getting 50 unique values from 1 to 50. That would in fact be so unlikely as to be the complete opposite of random. Imagine flipping a coin twice. One quarter of the times you get two heads, one quarter two tails, only half the time do you get a head and a tail.

Comment: If you dont want duplicates, then you have to keep track of which ones you already used. You can use a dictionary for that, although it does seem like a bit of just an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 4):

"Random sort" approach:

```vb
Sub tester()
    
    Dim arr, newArr
    
    arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("ROW(1:50)")) 'array 1 to 50
    
    Debug.Print "Original:" & vbLf & Join(arr, vbLf)
    
    SortSpecial arr, "RandomVal"

    Debug.Print "Rearranged:" & vbLf & Join(arr, vbLf)

    'put arr into the worksheet...

End Sub

'Sorts an array using some specific translation defined in `func`
Sub SortSpecial(list, func As String)
    Dim First As Long, Last As Long, i As Long, j As Long, tmp, arrComp()
    First = LBound(list)
    Last = UBound(list)
    'fill the "compare array...
    ReDim arrComp(First To Last)
    For i = First To Last
        arrComp(i) = Application.Run(func, list(i))
    Next i
    'now sort by comparing on `arrComp` not `list`
    For i = First To Last - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Last
            If arrComp(i) > arrComp(j) Then
                tmp = arrComp(j)          'swap positions in the "comparison" array
                arrComp(j) = arrComp(i)
                arrComp(i) = tmp
                tmp = list(j)             '...and in the original array
                list(j) = list(i)
                list(i) = tmp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Function RandomVal(v)
    RandomVal = Rnd()
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if one has ***Microsoft365***, this is quite possibly through a single (though volatile) formula:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=INDEX(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(50),RANDARRAY(50)),SEQUENCE(10,5))
```

---

**Some explanation:**

<sub>Step-1:</sub> `SEQUENCE(50)` - Retrieve an array from 1-50 (so no duplicates).

<sub>Step-2:</sub> `RANDARRAY(50)` - Retrieve an array of 50 random values.

<sub>Step-3:</sub> `SORTBY(Step1,Step2)` - Sort the 1st array according to the 2nd to create a total random set of values from 1-50 without duplicates.

<sub>Step-4:</sub> `INDEX(Step3, SEQUENCE(10,5))` - We can now "slice" our array in chunks of 10 rows over 5 columns.

Answer (score 2):

### Random Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub writeRandomRange()
    
    Const CellAddress As String = "A1"
    Const First As Long = 1
    Const Last As Long = 50
    Const rCount As Long = 10
    Const cCount As Long = 5
    
    If Last - First + 1 >= rCount * cCount Then
        Dim arr As Variant: arr = RandomDictionaryToArray(First, Last)
        Dim Data() As Long: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
        Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
        For r = 1 To rCount
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(r, c) = arr(n)
                n = n + 1
            Next c
        Next r
        Range(CellAddress).Resize(rCount, cCount).Value = Data
    Else
        MsgBox "There are not enough numbers.", vbCritical, "Fail"
    End If
    
End Sub

Function RandomDictionaryToArray( _
    ByVal LowOrHigh As Long, _
    ByVal HighOrLow As Long) _
As Variant
    
    ' Define the Numbers Dictionary ('dict').
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Define the lower number ('Minimum') and the Number of Elements ('NoE').
    Dim NoE As Long
    Dim Minimum As Long
    If LowOrHigh < HighOrLow Then
        Minimum = LowOrHigh
        NoE = HighOrLow - LowOrHigh + 1
    Else
        Minimum = HighOrLow
        NoE = LowOrHigh - HighOrLow + 1
    End If
    
    ' Write the unique random list of numbers to the Numbers Dictionary.
    Dim Current As Long
    Do
        Randomize ' Takes considerably longer.
        Current = Int(Minimum + NoE * Rnd)
        dict(Current) = Empty
    Loop Until dict.Count = NoE
    
    ' Write the result.
    RandomDictionaryToArray = dict.Keys

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This will 'randomly' put the values 1 to 50 into A1:E10 without repetition.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim rw As Long
Dim cl As Long
Dim num As Long

    num = 1

    Do
        rw = Application.RandBetween(1, 10)
        cl = Application.RandBetween(1, 5)

        If Cells(rw, cl).Value = "" Then
            Cells(rw, cl) = num
            num = num + 1
        End If
    Loop Until Application.CountBlank(Range("A1:E10")) = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Your last line `Loop Until Application.CountBlank(Range("A1:A10")) = 0` i think the range should be `A1:E10` instead of `A1:A10`

Comment: So it should be, didn't seem to affect the code though - strange.

Answer (score 0):

Generate 50 random numbers, write them to the cell, and calculate the ranks so that duplicate items do not occur.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim FillRange As Range, c As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim vR(1 To 50), a(1 To 50)
    Dim vDB
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    
    Set FillRange = Range("A1:A10")
    
    For i = 1 To 50
        vR(i) = Rnd
    Next i
    
    'write random number to the cell
    Set rng = Range("i1").Resize(1, 50)
    rng = vR
    
    'calcuclate the ranks
    For i = 1 To 50
        a(i) = WorksheetFunction.Rank(vR(i), rng)
    Next
    
    Set FillRange = Range("A1:e10")
    vDB = FillRange
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            n = n + 1
            vDB(i, j) = a(n)
        Next j
    Next i
    FillRange = vDB
    
End Sub
```

### image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that assigns the cells to the numbers in random order. You can change the size of the matrix.

```
Private Sub CmdFill_Click()
    ' 186
    
    Dim Rng         As Range                ' target range
    Dim C           As Long                 ' random column
    Dim R           As Long                 ' random row
    Dim Tmp         As Variant              ' random address
    Dim Spike       As String               ' used addresses
    Dim n           As Integer              ' loop counter: 1 to 50
    
    Set Rng = Range("A1:E10")               ' change to suit
    Randomize
    With Rng
        .ClearContents
        For n = 1 To .Cells.Count
            If n < (.Cells.Count - 2) Then
                Do
                    R = Int((.Rows.Count - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
                    C = Int((.Columns.Count - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
                    Tmp = Cells(R, C).Address(0, 0)
                Loop While InStr(Spike, Tmp)
                Range(Tmp).Value = n
                Spike = Spike & Tmp & ","
            Else
                ' select the last 3 by availability
                Tmp = .Value
                For R = 10 To 1 Step -1
                    For C = 1 To 5
                        If IsEmpty(Tmp(R, C)) Then
                            Cells(R, C).Value = n
                            R = 1
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next C
                Next R
            End If
        Next n
    End With
End Sub
```

I've programmed it so that you can change the size of the matrix (when you define the range at the top of the code) but it must start in A1. Starting in another cell will require a little modification.

The code will find unused cells at random. Toward the end this becomes time consuming. Therefore I stopped the process for the last 3 numbers. For them the code just looks for remaining blank cells and assigns the numbers to them. You can change the number of cells filled in that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
I made a version where you pull random items from the collection of 50 unique numbers:

Sub test()
    Dim maxNum As Long: maxNum = 50
    Dim nums As Collection
    Set nums = FillCollection(maxNum)  'Fill our collection with all nums to be used

    Dim count As Long
    For count = 1 To maxNum
        'Place a random item from our collection into the next cell
        Sheet1.Cells(count, 1).Value = PullRandObjFromCollection(nums)
    Next count

End Sub

Function FillCollection(ByVal maxNum As Long) As Collection
    Set FillCollection = New Collection
    Dim count As Long
    For count = 1 To maxNum
        FillCollection.Add count, CStr(count)
    Next count
End Function

Function PullRandObjFromCollection(ByRef coll As Collection) As Variant
    Dim randNum As Double
    randNum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, coll.count)

    PullRandObjFromCollection = coll.Item(randNum)
    coll.Remove randNum   'this function permanently alters the Collection
End Function
```