# Generating random number. How can I ensure no duplicates?

Tags: excel, vba, random

I'm writing an inventory application. For each entry, I need a random number as a ID for the transaction.

```vb
Randomize 10
newIDnum = Int(Rnd * 1000000)
```

I have validation built in. If a duplicate is added I get alerted.

I understand little about seeds and where the CPU gets the info to generate a random number (I understand it's not truly random).

I need to make sure that no duplicate values are generated, or at least that I minimize the probability as low as possible.

Comment: If you get a duplicate then pick another number until you don't?  Why not just use an incrementing sequence though?

Comment: Some recent solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466723/i-want-data-of-50-random-array-with-5-column-and-10-row-with-unique-and-no-dupl)

Comment: There are some exceedingly long pseudo-random sequences that will give you nearly an unlimited number of seemingly random values without duplicates. But as Tim says, why not use an incrementing sequence though?

Comment: You do not really want random numbers because truly random numbers contain duplicates.  You can reject duplicates as you pick, or you can use a random shuffle of the set of numbers you want.  For a very large set you can adapt an encryption algorithm as well, though that is overkill for smaller sets.

Answer (score 0):

You could record each used number in a sheet.

```vb
Option Base 1

Option Explicit

Sub UniqueIDsInRandomOrder()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim newIDnum As Long
Dim maxID As Long
Dim cellCount As Long

maxID = 10000000
maxID = 30  ' for testing

Dim retryConfirmatiom As Long

'To stop if there is a problem
retryConfirmatiom = 50

Randomize 10

tryAgain:
j = j + 1

newIDnum = Int(Rnd * maxID)
newIDnum = newIDnum + 1
If newIDnum > maxID Then newIDnum = maxID
'Debug.Print newIDnum

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(newIDnum, 1) <> 0 Then
    'Debug.Print "Duplicate: " & rndNum(newIDnum)
    
    If j > retryConfirmatiom Then
        cellCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
        j = 0
        
        If cellCount < maxID Then
            ' Continue trying if list is almost full.
            ' Also useful to exit potential endless loop due to GoTo.
            If MsgBox("Try again?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirm retry") = vbNo Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
        Else
            MsgBox "Appears all IDs used.", vbCritical, "Verify the list."
            Exit Sub
            
        End If
        
    End If
    
    ' Avoid if you can work out other logic
    GoTo tryAgain

End If

' You could record "1" rather than the number.
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(newIDnum, 1) = newIDnum

End Sub
```